# jQuery - How to select elements containing only certain other element

Tags: jquery

How do I select the nodes that have <a name="something"></a>, so that I can bold its contained text?

```
<p>
  <a name="test"></a>
  Test 1
</p>

<p>
  <a href="test2"></a>
  Test 2
</p>

<div>
  <a name="test3"></a>
  Test 3
</div>
```

Desired output:

**Test 1**

Test 2

**Test 3**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method:

```
$("p,div").has("a[name]").css("font-weight", "bold");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

or [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$("p:has(a[name]),div:has(a[name])").css("font-weight", "bold");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bWvwa/

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in my large document as it crashes the browser.  I've accepted your answer, however, I think I'll re-ask the question in PHP DOMDocument since that's how I've done all of my other processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[name="something"]').css('fontWeight', 'bold');
```